# json and http client slow

Tags: android, httpclient

I have a json parser which is parsing from a url, the app works on WiFi without problems and fast enough but on mobile network it's very slow and most of time not working.
The speed of the mobile network is good enough that whatsapp is working fast, so I don't know if the problem is related to Json parser or http client.

```
    // Async Task to access the web
    public String makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

        HttpParams params1 = new BasicHttpParams();
        params1.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params1);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

Comment: as i can see, you put all this code inside an AsyncTask, since AsyncTask runs on the background, it shouldn't slow your app. A couple of quick reasons may be, that the data being downloaded is taking too much time, that the app is waiting for the asynctask to complete; Your data network is slow; Your httpServer is not responding fast enough.

Comment: no the data is only 5 kb the network not slow it's good enough to whatsapp works fine

Comment: next time you need to log the DNS resolution time. There are some rare situations where there is one extra delay related to IPv4 and IPv6 compatibilities. Check RFC-6555 and RFC-8305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use any third party tools,which have inbuilt features to make your request fast.

[AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) : 
HTTP requests happen outside the UI thread
Automatic gzip response decoding support for super-fast requests

[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

finally [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)
Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster
You can see this information from [developer.android.com-training-volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)